# Polymer web component content click event not firing

Tags: javascript, polymer, web-component, dom-events, shadow-dom

I've just created my first element as a test and I'm running into an issue with an on-click event. My element is simply a button with a click event to increment a counter which is displayed as part of the button text. I've also added a content tag so you can add additional text to the button.

When I go to click the button in Chrome, if I click on the content text, the click event isn't fired. I have to actually click on the button element / the count in the button to fire the event. All seems to be working properly though in Firefox, Safari and Opera. I can click anywhere on the button in those browsers and the click event will fire. Am I doing something wrong? Is this just a bug with Chrome? Here is my code:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test Element</title>
    <script src="bower_components/platform/platform.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="elements/my-counter.html">
</head>
<body unresolved touch-action="auto">
    <my-counter count=5>Times a Day</my-counter>
</body>
</html>
```

**elements/my-counter.html**

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">

<polymer-element name="my-counter" attributes="count">
    <template>
        <button on-click="{{increment}}">{{ count }} <content></content></button>
    </template>
    <script>
    Polymer('my-counter', {
        count: 0,
        increment: function(event, detail, sender) {
            console.log(event, detail, sender);
            ++this.count;
        }
    });
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

This code is also on GitHub if you would like to download it and test it yourself: https://github.com/andersryanc/playing-with-polymer/tree/master/my-counter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wrap your extra text in a `span` it works.

```
<my-counter><span>Times a Day</span></my-counter>
```

See this [JSbin](http://jsbin.com/docij/2/edit?html,console,output).

I guess this is related to the fact that `textNodes`don't fire most events (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789342/textnode-addeventlistener)). 
If you mix `LightDOM` and `ShadowDOM` with events, make sure you read this [article](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom-301/#toc-events) and this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24480808/how-are-shadow-dom-events-from-under-content-targeted).

The reason that your code behaves differently in Chrome vs other browsers is that Chrome is currently the only browser shipping a native shadow dom implementation. Firefox is set to ship theirs in a couple weeks. More up to date info here: [caniuseit - shadowdom](http://caniuse.com/shadowdom)