# event.target changed in setTimeout in Shadow DOM?

Tags: javascript, web-component, shadow-dom

https://jsbin.com/qogewewomi/1/edit?html,js,output

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <test-test></test-test>
  <button id='out'>Outside Shadow DOM</button>
</body>

</html>
```

```js
customElements.define('test-test', class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();

    const node = document.createElement('template');
    node.innerHTML = '<button id="in">Inside Shadow DOM</button>';
    this.attachShadow({
      mode: 'open'
    }).appendChild(node.content);

    this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#in').addEventListener('click', e => {
      console.log(e.target);
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(e.target);
      });
    });
  }
});

document.querySelector('#out').addEventListener('click', e => {
  console.log(e.target);
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(e.target);
  });
});
```

I found these inconsistent behaviors inside an event listener inside and outside of shadow DOM. When the `Inside Shadow DOM` button is clicked, the console outputs:

```
<button id="in">Inside Shadow DOM</button>
<test-test>...</test-test>
```

When the `Outside Shadow DOM` button is clicked, the console outputs:

```
<button id="out">Outside Shadow DOM</button>
<button id="out">Outside Shadow DOM</button>
```

Tested in Chrome, FireFox and Safari. They all have these inconsistent behaviors. I don't know if this is expected behavior or a bug?

Update:
This question should not be closed. The other one doesn't answer this question.

Answer (score 3):

It is expected behavior, **not** a bug.

Explaining it will take too many characters.

See:

- [event currentTarget changes after setTimeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39649156/event-currenttarget-changes-after-settimeout)
- https://javascript.info/shadow-dom-events
- https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dispatching-events
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/Comparison_of_Event_Targets

---

In my simple words:

> Javascript is single-threaded.
> The (e) `Event` is a **global** Object passed around all Event Handlers

When you use a SetTimeout the `Event` content can/will be different

I rewrote your test code:

```html
<shadow-element id="lightcoral" title=One></shadow-element>
<script>
  function log(label, color, scope, evt) {
    let composedTarget = (evt.composed && evt.composedPath());
    console.log(`%c ${label} \t%c ${evt.target.id} `, `background:${color}`, `background:${evt.target.id};color:white`, '\n\ttarget:', evt.target, "\n\tthis:", scope.nodeName || "window", "\n\tcurrentTarget", evt.currentTarget, '\n\tclickedTarget:', evt.clickedTarget, "\n\tcomposed:", evt.composed ? "True" : "False", "composedPath[0]:", composedTarget[0]);
  }

  customElements.define('shadow-element', class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      super().attachShadow({mode:'open'})
             .innerHTML = `<button id=green>click ${this.title}</button>`;
      let button = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('button');
      button.onclick = e => {
        let savedTarget = e.target;
        e.clickedTarget = e.target;
        button.onclick = false; //prevent double capture
        log(`clicked element:${this.id}`, 'lightgreen', this, e);
        setTimeout(() => {
          log('timeout element', 'red;color:yellow', this, e)
        }, 500);
      };
      //this.onclick = button.onclick;
    }
  });

</script>
```

### To output:

[image]

`target` now is the `<shadow-element>` because once the `setTimeout` runs the **global** Event was passed all the way up the DOM.

`currentTarget` tells you all Event processing is done
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget

`clickedTarget` demonstrates you can set **custom** properties on that **global** Event object (being passed around). And thus 'save' the target you clicked. But.. other events (or the element.onclick function call below) could overwrite it, so better set a custom variable `savedTarget` in the correct scope, and use that in your `setTimeout`

---

You can see how `target`changes by setting a click handler on the element itself.

`target` becomes the `<shadow-element>` the moment the Event bubbles up the DOM and  'escapes' shadowDOM

[image]

Answer (score -1):

The main point being made [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24480808/how-are-shadow-dom-events-from-under-content-targeted) is that Events that do fire on elements in the Shadow DOM are **retargeted**, in order to hide the Shadow DOM from the Light one. This means that during its lifetime the Event object will get its `target` changed.

- First at the capturing phase, while the Event object still hasn't reached the Shadow DOM, the Light container (here `<test-test>`) will be the target of that Event object.
- Then inside the Shadow DOM, it will get changed to the actual Shadow target (`<button>`).
- Finally, at the bubbling phase when getting out of the Shadow DOM, it will be set back to the Light container.

So when you log it from the timeout, all the event phases will have occurred and the Event object will be in this final state with the Light container as `.target`.

```js
customElements.define('test-test', class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();

    const node = document.createElement('template');
    node.innerHTML = '<button id="in">Inside Shadow DOM</button>';
    this.attachShadow({
      mode: 'open'
    }).appendChild(node.content);

    this.shadowRoot.addEventListener('click', e => {
      console.log("[capturing phase] in Shadow DOM", e.target);
    }, { capture: true });
    this.shadowRoot.addEventListener('click', e => {
      console.log("[bubbling phase] in Shadow DOM", e.target);
    }, { capture: false });

  }
});

document.addEventListener('click', e => {
  console.log( "[capturing phase] in Light DOM", e.target);
}, { capture: true });
document.addEventListener('click', e => {
  console.log( "[bubbling phase] in Light DOM", e.target);
}, { capture: false });
```

```html
<test-test></test-test>
```

Comment: So does it mean if I want to use the same target in setTimeout in shadow dom, I will have to store the variable locally?

Comment: @QianChen yes you need to grab it from when the event fires synchronously (you could also get it from outside the open Shadow DOM through `e.composedPath()[0]`, but this returns an empty Array after a timeout.)

Comment: Depends on where you want to use it. Add it as variable within the listener scope and it is only available within that scope. Add it as extra property on the event and is available to all handlers the event is processed by.